# How can I prove this problem on geometry?

Tags: geometry

I need to prove the following:

> If $P$ is an inner point of $\triangle ABC$, then there is a single transverse $EF$ of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, where $E$ is on $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and $F$ is on $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, such that P is the middle of the segment $XY$.

I tried for a longer time but nothing!! Some idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on @noneEggs's suggestion.

[image]

1: Extend BP to Q such that BP = (0.5) BQ

2: (Can be skipped.) A circle (centered at P and radius = PB) is drawn cutting BP extended at Q.

3: A line through Q is drawn parallel to AB cutting AC (extended if necessary) at R.

4: Join BR.

5: A line through Q is drawn parallel to RB cutting AB at S.

6: Join SR.

According to the construction, SBRQ is a parallelogram with diagonals BQ and SR cutting each other at T.

Since the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other, BT = (0.5) BQ. This, together with the result in (1), means that T and P are the same point. Thus, RPS is a straight line with SP = PR.

R and S are then the required E and F respectively.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see this more clear!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint : You can always make a parallelogram out of A and P, where A is a vertex and P is the center of the parallelogram itself

Comment: In fact, you can always make many of this!! But what is the idea in your hint?